# trigger('click') works but does not trigger some of the code on codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Once I click the button it triggers another button which adds content of textboxes to the database but if i click the button itself without triggering it through javascript it runs `label.text="blabla";` too which is what I want from jQuery trigger. Here is jQuery code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        $("input[id$='BtnFirst']").click(function () {
            $("input[id$='SubmitEkle']").trigger("click");
            $("#label_ekle").fadeIn();                       
            $("#label_ekle").fadeOut(3000);
            alert("clicked button #1");
        });           
    });
</script>
```

I solved this problem as shown below:

```
 function MyFadeOut(){


            $(".lblkullanicieklendi").fadeIn();
            $(".lblkullanicieklendi").fadeOut(3000);
        }
```

//Codebehind button click event

```
 protected void Ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
    {
    something something...

     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp",
            "<script type='text/javascript'>MyFadeOut();</script>", false);
    }
       catch {}

    }
```

Comment: *it runs label.text="blabla"; too which is what I want from jQuery trigger* ,can you please clarify what is meant by this

Comment: After I click the button it adds content of textboxes to database and if it added them to database succesfully label text changes. but if i trigger that button with jQuery it still adds them to database but does not change label text.